# "Identity for" in Boolean algebra

Tags: discrete-mathematics, boolean-algebra

In Susanna Epp's book Discrete Mathematics with applications I came across phrases such as "... is an identity for +" or "...is an identity for *", for example

> There is only one element of $B$ that is an identity for +

The identity **law** for + is $a+0=a$, that makes sense. But "$0$ is an identity for +" sounds meaningless to me. What does it mean in the context of these phrases /quote?

Comment: "...is an identity with respect to the addition operation..."

Comment: See [Identity element](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_element): "In mathematics, an identity element, or neutral element, is a special type of element of a set with respect to a binary operation on that set, which leaves any element of the set unchanged when combined with it."

Comment: Thus, "... is an identity for +" is a shorthand for ""... is an identity element with respect to the binary operation +".

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA makes sense now, thank you. “ The term identity element is often shortened to identity (as in the case of additive identity and multiplicative identity), when there is no possibility of confusion”. Haha so there was such a possibility. Weird it was never mentioned in the book.